# Silent notification vs Background fetch

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile, silent-notification

I've already read [Apple's documentation on background modes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html), but I still have some questions.

Please correct me if I'm wrong:

To enable remote notifications: I **only** need to do:[image]

To enable silent notifications: I need to enable Push notifications like above and also enable **remote notifications**
[image]

My questions are:

1. Are the above statements correct?
2. For handling silent notifications, do I **ever** need to enable `background fetch` from Xcode Capabilities? Or that has nothing to do with silent notifications and it's only to be used when you want to trigger an *interval-based* download that **isn't** triggered from *server*.

Answer (score 4):

**Answer for 1st question :** Yes Correct, You have to enable both options, Background mode - Remote notification and push notifications if you need to listen silent push notification also. Else enable only push notification

**Answer for 2nd question :** Background fetch is not related with push/silent notification. Your app will listen the silent push notification only if you enable the background mode **remote notification**. Otherwise OS won't allow your app to listen silent push notification.

Comment: and so it has nothing to do with `background fetch`?

Comment: Background fetch - Applications with the "fetch" background mode may be given opportunities to fetch updated content in the background or when it is convenient for the system. Its nothing related with push notification

Comment: func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Swift.Void) { }.  This method will be called in these situations. You should call the fetchCompletionHandler as soon as you're finished performing that operation, so the system can accurately estimate its power and data cost.

Comment: have you answered my comment above? The answer is yes or no...I'm not able to understand what's yours

Comment: Background fetch is not related with push notification

Comment: First you should know what is "background fetch" then you will come to know weather it is required or not.